# What's the best way to get an audio buffer into a blob that can be played by an audio element?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

I have an AudioBuffer stored as a variable, and I would like to have it be played by an Audio element. Here is my current non-functioning code:

```
const blob = new Blob(audioBuffer.getChannelData(1), { type: "audio/wav" });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audioElement.src = url;
```

When I try to play audioElement, I get the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AudioBuffer is PCM data, not encoded as WAV yet.  If you need WAV you should get a library to do the encoding for you, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav

After including above code (you can just copy the audioBufferToWav function and the functions it calls below it out of index.js).

```js
const blob = new Blob([audioBufferToWav(audioBuffer.getChannelData(1))], { type: "audio/wav" });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audioElement.src = url;
```

Below using Web Audio API to playback the PCM AudioBuffer directly.

```js
var myArrayBuffer = audioBuffer;
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
source.start();
```

Comment: I'm not really attached to WAV at all, would encoding to WAV be the simplest way to get this audiobuffer into the src of an audio element?

Comment: Yes.  There may be a better way depending on what it is you are doing, such as using createMediaElementSource.  But given an AudioBuffer that needs to be attached to an audio element, yes, encoding to a WAV is the simplest way to go about it.